# replace $1 variable in file with 1-10000

Tags: bash, command-line, sed

I want to create 1000s of this one file.

All I need to replace in the file is one var

```
    kitename = $1
```

But i want to do that 1000s of times to create 1000s of diff files.

I'm sure it involves a loop.

people answering people is more effective than google search!
thx

Comment: What have you tried? People will be more willing to help you if you put some effort in yourself.

Comment: your right. thank you for your insight. just juggling a lot of tasks @ the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not really sure what you are asking here, but the following will create 1000 files named filename.n containing 1 line each which is "kite name = n" for n = 1 to n = 1000

```
for i in {1..1000}
do
echo "kitename = $i" > filename.$i
done
```

Comment: yup, that's a start I can take it from here. i'll post my completed code. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mysql installed, it comes with a *lovely* command line util called "replace" which replaces files in place across any number of files. Too few people know about this, given it exists on most linux boxen everywhere. Syntax is easy:

```
replace SEARCH_STRING REPLACEMENT -- targetfiles*
```

If you MUST use sed for this... that's okay too :) The syntax is similar:

```
sed -i.bak s/SEARCH_STRING/REPLACEMENT/g targetfile.txt
```

So if you're just using numbers, you'd use something like:

```
for a in {1..1000}
  do
     cp inputFile.html outputFile-$a.html
     replace kitename $a -- outputFile-$a.html
 done
```

This will produce a bunch of files "outputFile-1.html" through "outputFile-1000.html", with the word "kitename" replaced by the relevant number, inside the file.

But, if you want to read your lines from a file rather than generate them by magic, you might want something more like this (we're not using "for a in `cat file`" since that splits on words, and I'm assuming here you'd have maybe multi-word replacement strings that you'd want to put in:

```
cat kitenames.txt | while read -r a
  do
     cp inputFile.html "outputFile-$a.html"
     replace kitename "$a" -- kitename-$a
  done
```

This will produce a bunch of files like "outputFile-red kite.html" and "outputFile-kite with no string.html", which have the word "kitename" replaced by the relevant name, inside the file.